# How to attach an image to a border after the border line (not inside the border)

Tags: html, css, angular

Here is the link to get an idea what I am trying to do.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizable?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

in here.. instead of darkgrey I want to add an image in that palce.

I have tried something like this but it is not working

this.el.nativeElement.style["border-right"] = this.resizableGrabWidth + "url('image.svg')";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A border image can not be specified on "border-right" but only for all borders at once using the border-image style. Try this:

```
this.el.nativeElement.style["border-right"] = this.resizableGrabWidth + "px solid transparent"; 
this.el.nativeElement.style["border-image"] = "url(assets/border.png) 30 round";
```

The border image will only appear on the right when that is the only border with none-zero width.
(See also: [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image) )